# Automatically convert imports from 'import { A } from 'flowbite-svelte'' to 'import A from 'flowbite-svelte/A.svelte''

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to automatically convert imports from something like `import { A } from 'flowbite-svelte'` to `import A from 'flowbite-svelte/A.svelte'`?

Here's another example of what I want:

From

```
import { Button } from 'flowbite-svelte'
```

to

```
import Button from 'flowbite-svelte/Button.svelte'
```

I'm using svelte kit, vite, typescript, prettier, and es lint.

I need this so I can optimize the page load times

Comment: I don't think so there is a way. But if there is, I'll be very excited to know!